# Question regarding the additional hot wire

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I installed a ceiling fan recently and it required me to use black (hot), white (neutral) and ground wire. The rough-in had an additional hot wire (red) which was left unused because the fan had remote functionality.
My question is that can I use this unused hot wire to connect to another wire and connect that wire to ceiling lights?

Comment: I take it the red wire is connected to another switch in the switch box that has the fan switch in it?

Comment: The Red could also be a switched hot

Comment: Right, could be for individual fan/light switching.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that is correct. Red wire is connected to another switch in the switch box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To really figure this out, we need a picture showing all cables/wires in the *switch box*. That will tell us, definitively, whether this is one switch switching two wires, one switch switching one wire (with the other wire always hot) or two switches each switching one wire.

Black, red, white and ground in the ceiling box can actually fit 3 different scenarios. From this point forward, the bare ground wires will be ignored as they are not relevant to this situation - they should be in every cable, connected to metal boxes, connected to every device.

- Switch loop
- Always hot (typically black) included as well as switched hot (typically red)
- Two switched hots (black and red)

A switch loop would, typically, send hot down to the switch on black and neutral on white and bring switched hot back up on red. However, it also requires an additional cable (black/white) for incoming power. Since OP did not mention a second cable, I will assume that this is *not* a switch loop.

So that leaves two very different possibilities:

- Always hot included as well as switched hot

This seems a little odd to me. Why would a typical penny-pinching builder include an extra wire (always hot) when it is not required? But it is possible. If this is the case then the fan black wire should actually be connected to the *red* wire, not the black wire. Doing so will allow the wall switch to actually turn the fan/light on and off. However, depending on the design of the fan control (fan/light remote? fan speed controller remote? pull string switches?) that wall switch may or may not function as expected.

- Two switched hots

This is the traditional configuration for a fan/light - one switched hot to the fan, one switched hot to the light. In this case, the second switched hot can be connected to a separate light (i.e., it doesn't have to be part of the fan) as OP wants, with the neutral (white) extended as well. Don't worry about the colors - you can use black for the fan and add a black/white cable to extend *red*/white to the light fixture.

However, it is extremely common for a fan to include a remote control module. The remote control module gets *always hot* (which often means "wall switch with a piece of tape over it so nobody turns it off") and the remote is placed on the wall next to it to use for turning on/off the light (and often dimming it as well) and turning on/off the fan (and often speed control as well).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am unable to add a picture of the switch box. Your point to ‘Two switched hots’ is more applicable in this case. Its 14/3 romex wire and black is connected to one switch and the red is connected to another switch.

Comment: With confirmation that black is connected to one switch and red to the other, yes you have a two switch configuration, very common for non-remote fan + light, and yes you can use the other switch for a separate light fixture.

Comment: thank you, that clarifies my question.

Answer (score 1):

The original wiring idea was to provide a constant hot,(black) a switched hot,(Red) a neutral (white) and a ground (bare copper or green)to the fan box.

If the red wire is unused, and it is switched, you can run cable from the fan box to another box to be used for lights or other low amperage devices, and continue to other boxes.

You do need to check that the circuit will not be overloaded.

Your other limitation is the capacity of the box. If needed and possible you will have to change to a box with a larger CU capacity. This also depends on the size of wire you have.  (more info is needed here to determine an actual go or no go for your lights)

If box size and circuit usage are ok you can proceed to add cable to another box for lights.

For the new circuit to the lights; tie all the neutrals together in the fan box.
The grounds get tied together and the hot (black) from the new cable is tied to the red.

Before tying any wires together be sure to turn off the breaker to the circuit.